# SwiftUI Type 'Color' has no member 'red'. swiftui is not reloading when data updated in @published object

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui

I have existing project from iOS10 onwards , I have updated to iOS13 and using SwiftUI views , this swiftUI view loaded using UIHostingController

```
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: HomeView(viewModel: HelloViewModel()))
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

My viewmodel has `@Published public var sampData = ["Ramu","somu","Beemu","Kaamu"]` and it has used in my view .
First thing : View is not reloading while data has updating either append new items or removing existing items . and has a strange error like "Type 'Color' has no member 'red'" , I do not have idea what is causing the issue

```
struct AllergiesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : HelloViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(viewModel.sampData , id : \.self) { data in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text("Hello")){
                        Text(data)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(){
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Users")
    }
}
```

and my viewmodel init look like this

```
init() {
        var runCount = 0

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.sampData.append("\(runCount)")
            }
            print(self.sampData)
            runCount += 1

            if runCount == 5 {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps Color is a type you defined elsewhere and SwiftUI is inferring that instead of SwiftUI's Color type? If so, you can disambiguate by changing Color to SwiftUI.Color

Comment: What are you trying to color in red? Usually you’d put the colour as a modifier on something so in this case if you are trying to color your ZStack then you’d put it after the ZStack closure brace

Comment: main thing is UI not reloading

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @rlong405 `Color` conforms to `View` in SwiftUI so it is valid to use it as shown.

Comment: @Prathap I just dropped your code into a new SwiftUI app and it worked without any issues.  One thing I would do is set a breakpoint or add a `print` to your view model `init`- If you create the view model at the wrong place in your view hierarchy you can end up with the situation where new view models are continually created as the view hierarchy is recreated,

Comment: Yes , for new project it's working fine , but it's a new screen in existing project (xib) , elements adding in array fine but UI not updating

Comment: Can you add more code? A [mcve]? How is `HelloViewModel` related to `AllergiesViewModel`?

Comment: @Paulw11 it's same viewmodel , and I have passed that viewmodel as a constructor parameter . If I create new project it's working fine , same code not working in existing project